# In Visualforce, Does "rendered" reexecutes after "reRender" refreshes a section?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I am trying to hide the section 'searchCriteria' when 'Edit' link is clicked. The hiding is done in Controller 'editSearchResult()' method using 'pageLoad' variable.

The 'pageLoad' is used in 'searchCriteria' section with rendered attribute. But, the section is not refreshing with updated values from Controller when Edit link is clicked.

But if I remove 'rendered' attribute on the section 'searchCriteria', system refreshes the section with updated values from Controller. Can anyone explain how 'rendered' handles display?

## Visualforce Code:

```
<apex:page controller="RerenderDemoController">
    <apex:form id="thisForm">
        <apex:outputPanel id="searchCriteria" rendered="{!pageLoad}">
            <apex:pageBlock>
                <apex:pageBlockSection>
                    This is Search Criteria Section. Page Load: {!pageLoad}, 
                    User: <apex:outputText value="{!userName}"> 
        </apex:outputText> 
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:outputPanel>

        <apex:outputPanel id="searchResults">
            <apex:pageBlock>
                <apex:pageBlockSection>
                    This is Search Results Section. {!accts}
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:outputPanel>

        <apex:outputPanel id="EditResult">
            <apex:pageBlock>
                <apex:pageBlockSection>
                    This is Edit Result Section.
                    <apex:commandLink action="{!editSearchResult}" reRender="searchCriteria">Edit</apex:commandLink>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

## Apex Controller:

```
public class RerenderDemoController {
    public List<Account> accts {get; set;}
    public Boolean pageLoad {get; set;}
    public String userName {get; set;}

    public RerenderDemoController() {
        pageLoad = true;
        userName = 'My First Name';
        accts = [select id, name from Account limit 10];
    }

    public void editSearchResult() {
        pageLoad = false;
        accts = [select id, name from Account limit 20];
        userName = 'My Last Name';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, wrap your `outputPanel` with another `outputPanel`

```
<apex:outputPanel id="searchCriteria">
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!pageLoad}">
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                This is Search Criteria Section. Page Load: {!pageLoad}, 
                User: <apex:outputText value="{!userName}"> 
                     </apex:outputText> 
           </apex:pageBlockSection>
         </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Hope, this will solve your issue.

Comment: Noor, 'rerender' attribute is not available on <apex:outputPanel> tag.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I am updating my answer. Hope it will work.

Comment: @SubhaniShaik: Thanks. As you mention it worked, can you please upvote my answer and mark it accepted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to Hide the content just use html class and use [jquery]:https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js

and use `$('.classname').hide();`
hope it helps you.